# How do I disable core WordPress styles editor UI in block themes?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, wordpress-block-theme

[image]

I'm having trouble figuring out how to disable the block theme styles UI when using the editor. I'd like to define these styles myself (in the theme and blocks styles), so I'd like to hide the styles interface completely to avoid confusion for the site admins.

I've tried various add_theme_support and remove_theme_support calls, passing an empty object to the styles key in the block.json file, etc. No luck.

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: I'm building a new theme from scratch using the block theme api (HTML template parts, block.json, etc.). I was hoping to find a filter, theme support, or theme.json option to disable this feature. Haven't found anything that works and no reference (that I've found) from the WordPress docs.